# How to count number of individuals with unique ids meeting criteria

Tags: r

This is an example data.

[image: table of data]

I would like help on what R codes to use to get the following:

Count the number of individuals (ages <11-years) with unique id, who have first1 = 1, bacteria = GAS, second2 = 2, & bacteria = GAS.

Count the number of individuals (ages <11-years) with unique id, who have first1 = 1, bacteria = GAS, second2 = 2 & bacteria = SA or No.

So that, would come to 1 person (age <11-years) has first1 = 1, bacteria = GAS, second2 = 2, & bacteria = GAS.

And, 3 people (age <11-years) have irst1 = 1, bacteria = GAS, second2 = 2 & bacteria = SA or No.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Krishtika Mala! Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: What is `first1`, should that be `infection1`?

Comment: Sorry, yes first1 should bf infection1.

Comment: data %>%
    filter(age < 11, infection1 == 1, second2 == 2) %>%
    mutate(
      bacteria2 = case_when(
        bacteria2 %in% c("SA", "No") ~ "SA or No",
        TRUE ~ bacteria2)
    ) %>%
    summarize(n = n_distinct(id), .by = bacteria2) 


This is code that was shared with me in the comments. However, when I use it it gives me the following error:

# A tibble: 0 × 2
# ℹ 2 variables: use_swab_results2 <chr>, n <int>

Comment: You've shared no data and your error code mentions a variable we know nothing about. Good luck!

Comment: Your expanded explanation says *"1 person initially positive for GAS and then positive for SA"*, but your question says *"count the number of individuals with unique id, ... bacteria = GAS"*. There is no "sequence" of bacteria. I do not understand the circuit logic. Please [edit] your question and provide (1) `dput(head(x,20))` (where x is your data); and (2) `data.frame(...)` (or `dput(..)`) of the expected output given that sample data in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one unverified technique to get your counts:

```r
library(dplyr) # dplyr_1.1.0 or newer for .by=

dat %>%
  filter(age < 11, infection1 == 1, second2 == 2) %>%
  mutate(
    bacteria2 = case_when(
      bacteria %in% c("SA", "No") ~ "SA or No",
      TRUE ~ bacteria)
  ) %>%
  summarize(n = n_distinct(id), .by = bacteria2)
```

---

*Edit*

After scraping the image of a table for something usable (thanks to the demo page at https://extracttable.com/v2/demo.html),

```r
dat <- structure(list(id = c("aaa1", "aaa1", "aaa1", "bbb1", "bbb1", "ddd0", "ghg1", "ghg1", "ggg1", "ggg1", "hcd5", "cdc6", "cdc6", "zsz1", "zsz2", "ara1", "ara1", "rra1", "rra1"), infection1 = c(1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA), second2 = c(NA, 2L, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L), bacteria = c("GAS", "GAS", "No", "GAS", "SA", "GAS", "SA", "GAS", "GAS", "GAS", "GAS", "No", "GAS", "GAS", "SA", "GAS", "No", "GAS", "GAS"), age = c(0L,  1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 3L, 14L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 14L, 15L), year = c(2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2016L, 2012L, 2013L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2013L, 2014L, 2013L, 2014L, 2010L, 2011L, 2010L, 2011L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
```

I tested my code against your data, and it in fact returns zero rows.

```r
dat %>%
  filter(age < 11, infection1 == 1, second2 == 2) %>%
  mutate(
    bacteria2 = case_when(
      bacteria %in% c("SA", "No") ~ "SA or No",
      TRUE ~ bacteria)
  ) %>%
  summarize(n = n_distinct(id), .by = bacteria2)
# [1] bacteria2 n        
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

This is due to the logic in your request:

- `infection1 = 1, second2 = 2` never occurs, one of them is `NA` in every row;

  ```
  xtabs(~ is.na(infection1) + is.na(second2), data =dat)
  #                  is.na(second2)
  # is.na(infection1) FALSE TRUE
  #             FALSE     0   10
  #             TRUE      9    0
  ```
- `bacteria = GAS & bacteria = SA or No` is self-contradictory.

In my answer I was assuming that your sample of data was more complete than what you took a screenshot of.

It might be more useful to return zeroes for the two bacteria classes (GAS and SA/No), so a quick mod to the above code:

```r
dat %>%
  mutate(
    use = age < 11 & infection1 %in% 1 & second2 %in% 2,
    bacteria2 = case_when(
      bacteria %in% c("SA", "No") ~ "SA or No",
      TRUE ~ bacteria)
  ) %>%
  summarize(n = n_distinct(id[use]), .by = bacteria2)
#   bacteria2 n
# 1       GAS 0
# 2  SA or No 0
```

Comment: Thank you. I used your codes, but I got an error:

# A tibble: 0 × 2
# ℹ 2 variables: use_swab_results2 <chr>, n <int>

Comment: See  my edit, @KrishtikaMala. The code works mostly, would you prefer that it returns a frame with two rows saying `0` counts for both?

Comment: Hi @r2evens. I am sorry if I am not being much help. I added below extra bit for information on what sort of answer I am trying to get. Thanks

Comment: Yes @r2evens, I would prefer a frame with rows saying n counts for both.

Comment: The NA is just an empty cell because the the first1 refers to first infection, and second2 refers to the 2nd or 3rd infection. The data is arranged that way. So the 1 in first1 means 1st infection. And the 2 in second2 means 2nd infection, and the 3 means 3rd infection per id.